# [Solved]: Error resolving image name 'debian-cloud/debian-9': Could not find image or family debian-cloud/debian-9

Tags: quest

- Google Cloud Skills Boost
- (Quest) Secure Workloads in Google Kubernetes Engine
- (Lab) Securing Applications on Kubernetes Engine - Three Examples

On the section "Provisioning the Kubernetes Engine cluster", run the command

```
make create
```

I got into an error:

```
enter code here

│ Error: Error resolving image name 'debian-cloud/debian-9': Could not find image or family debian-cloud/debian-9
│
│   with module.bastion.google_compute_instance.instance,
│   on modules/instance/main.tf line 54, in resource "google_compute_instance" "instance":
│   54: resource "google_compute_instance" "instance" {
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Run the command to see the available images

```
gcloud compute images list | grep debian
```

Step 2: At the project root, run the below command

```
vi ./terraform/modules/instance/main.tf
```

Step 3: At VIM normal mode, search for the debian-9 by type `/debian-9`, hit enter

```
// Specify the Operating System Family and version.
boot_disk {
initialize_params {
image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
}
}
```

Step 4: As my case, the debian-10 is available. So I change the above block code into

```
// Specify the Operating System Family and version.
boot_disk {
initialize_params {
image = "debian-cloud/debian-10"
}
}
```

Step 5: Change directory to the project root, then re-run the command `make create`.